# Laravel - What is the best approach to optimize update/insert queries with large data?

Tags: mysql, laravel, query-optimization

There are over 200 users loggedin. Each user insert/update 1000 records in child table `car_prices` per 15 minutes which is related to parent table `cars`.

```
CREATE TABLE `cars` (
    `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE `car_prices` (
    `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `car_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `price` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
    `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `car_prices_car_id_foreign` (`car_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Every 15 minutes users execute this query (As an example):

```
INSERT INTO `car_prices` VALUES(NULL, 1, 3000, NOW(), NOW())
INSERT INTO `car_prices` VALUES(NULL, 2, 7000, NOW(), NOW())
INSERT INTO `car_prices` VALUES(NULL, 3, 5000, NOW(), NOW())
// ...and many other inserts approximately 1000
```

OR

```
UPDATE `car_prices` SET `price` = 4000 WHERE `id` = 1;
UPDATE `car_prices` SET `price` = 8000 WHERE `id` = 2;
UPDATE `car_prices` SET `price` = 6000 WHERE `id` = 3;
// ...and many other updates approximately 1000
```

How can I overcome this issue? There are lots of data and it takes long time to update/insert. Should I do something special that MySQL might have like some features? Or the pattern might be wrong? Or I should use some features that Laravel might have?

Comment: What issue do you want to overcome?

Comment: @Strawberry it takes long time to update/insert.

Comment: You should insert your data in chunks (send SQL commands in chunks instead of sending them one by one). I can't offer any code because I don't know the full context of your inserts (where the data comes from, how is it stored, etc)

Comment: What are the users doing for the 14 minutes in between?

Comment: @Strawberry nothing. But I have calculated that users are inserting/updating every almost 15 minutes.

Comment: How long is each query actually taking? Are the users performing multiple updates at the same time or are they updating one price, then going to a different page and updating another?

Comment: I'm using queue and have ssd hard. it takes 1-2 minutes. Yeah multiple updates at the same time, if that was one by one it would be faster I think but the front-end has check-boxes. @Rwd

Comment: Please can you add the code for your Job and also the code that triggers your Job. Are you going off how long it takes the job to complete or the actual query time? Also, what is the reason the car price is in a different table?

Comment: Because it took long time the query to run so I used queue. So if I can do it without queue and you have an idea of doing that of course I would so I mean the actual query. They are in different table because the prices are from different sellers. @Rwd

Comment: I never asked why you were using a queue, I do get the reasoning behind it though. I asked if you could show the actual code you're using i.e. the `Job` class, the code that pushes the work on to the queue etc. Without actually seeing your code implementation there isn't really anything anyone can actually do to help.

Comment: @kodfire - It's up to the user to type the `ids` correctly?  And a typo could change someone else's car price?

Comment: How do you acquire the new ids from `INSERTs`?

Comment: High speed ingestion -- http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table ; This can be adapted for mass INSERT or UPDATE.  (Update is trickier.)

Answer (score 0):

You an performe this task in a more efficient way using chunks

See this example i'm using for daily cron job that synchronize my table products

```
    DB::beginTransaction();

    try {

        $response = json_decode(file_get_contents('API_URL_GOES_HERE'), true);

        if(!empty($response['products'])) {
             

            $tempArr = [];

            foreach ($response['products'] as $product) {

                $tempArr[] = [
                    'name' => $product['name'],
                    'price' => $product['price'],
                    'category_id' => $product['category_id'],
                ];
            }

            Product::truncate();

            $insertData = collect($tempArr);

            $chunks = $insertData->chunk(500);

            foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
                Product::insert($chunk->toArray());
            }

            DB::commit();

            dd($countProducts . ' Products imported successfully.');

        } else {

            dd('No products to import were found.');
        }

    } catch(\Exception $e) {

        DB::rollback();
        $this->info('');
        dump('Import failed : ' . $e->getMessage());
        dd('DB rolled back.');
    }
```